# How to find out if this SELECT query executed successfully?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Pname(in_empno IN NUMBER out_name OUT VARCHAR2)
 AS
 BEGIN
 select EmpName into out_name from emptable where Empno = in_empno;
 END Pname;
```

In the above procedure, how can I check if the SELECT query executed successfully or not with the given condition?

Comment: when you say successfully, are you expecting data to be returned?

Comment: Yes there should be some records returned for that condition

Comment: @user1 You would like to know whether your sql query executed successfully or what is the value of out_name?

Comment: prefixing the parameter names with "in_" and "out_" seems clumsy to me. If you are concerned about namespace problems in a query then prefix the pl/sql variable name with the name of the procedure (and the table column name with the name of the table or its alias), which is a more robust solution anyway. In other words, use EMPNO as the parameter name and in the query specify "where emptable.empno = pname.empno". Future user1 will be grateful to you eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `EXCEPTION` block to determine if rows were returned or if some other exceptions occurred. Try this

```
BEGIN
 SELECT EmpName into out_name from emptable where Empno = in_empno
 EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         out_name := NULL;
END;
```

Comment: @venkat thank you, can i find the affected rows with SQL%ROWCOUNT ? If so how to do it?

Comment: @user1 With respect to your query it makes no sense to find out effected rows, oracle will raise exception in case of no data found or more than one value returned by the query. SQL%ROWCOUNT will be used in update, delete and insert, not in select.

Comment: Hi Pravin Satav check this link, We can use SQL%ROWCOUNT in "SELECT' and i want to know how to use it. If anyone having example help me out. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm

Comment: the question is why %row count%? You can use `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rowCount from emptable where Empno = in_empno`. But I think that should return 1 or 0. Row count should be used to know number of rows deleted, inserted or updated.

Comment: @codingbiz im using count(*) only but in the link i posted they said v can use row count too, i didnt understand how it is used for 'SELECT' there my question arises.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see the output of out_name parameter try as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pname (in_empno IN NUMBER, out_name OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT  empName 
      INTO  out_name
      FROM  emptable
     WHERE  empno = in_empno;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        raise_application_error (
            -20000,
            'Unable to execute procedure because of: ' || SQLERRM
        );
END pname;
```

This procedure can be executed from sql plus as

```
var ret varchar2(512);

exec pname(2345,:ret);

print ret;
```

Update 1

If you would like to return a value if sql query executes successfully and if there is an error return another value then do as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pname (in_empno   IN        VARCHAR2,
                                              out_name        OUT VARCHAR2,
                                              returnval   IN OUT NUMBER
                                             )
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT  employee_name
      INTO  out_name
      FROM  employees
     WHERE  emp_number = in_empno;

    returnval := 0;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        returnval := 1;

END pname;
```

and call the procedure from sql plus as

```
var ret varchar2(512);
var ret2 number;

exec pname(2346,:ret,:ret2);

print ret;
print ret2;
```

Comment: thanku, If it comes to "EXCEPTION" loop what will it return while i execute exec pname(2345,:ret);  What will ret ll print

Comment: @user1 If there is an exception it will raise the exception with the error message, otherwise it will print the `empName`.

Answer (score 0):

In this example i can stop using one more out variable for return right? and ill check for the condition in my front end like if 'out_name' returns null ill handle in someway, if it returns value it'll be handled in other way, Which one is efficient?????Using one more out variable for Retvalue, or doing like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pname (in_empno   IN   VARCHAR2, out_name OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT  employee_name
  INTO  out_name
  FROM  employees
 WHERE  emp_number = in_empno;


EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        out_name := NULL;
  END;
```

Comment: Which is your front end application?

Comment: I am not aware of VC++, but from Java if there are any exceptions you can catch those exceptions with SQL Error Code and based on that you can do whatever you want in front end. IMHO if you can manage with out_name then no need to have another out parameter.